# Can I travel from Germany to England alone as an unaccompanied minor?

Tags: uk, air-travel, airports, minors, german-citizens

I currently live in Germany and am a German citizen.

My passport is from the United States of America as I used to be a citizen there.

I am moving to England (UK) alone.

I am 14 years old and will be flying internationally. I am unsure what problems I might run into in both airports, as I am a minor and will be travelling solo.

I have already seen posts about people travelling abroad as minors and have seen that security and police might question me.

Yes, I have an in-date passport, but I do not know if I will be able to get a visa if needed (I do not exactly understand what a visa is- I apologise.).

And no, I cannot get a letter of permission from either of my parents (It is a... Complicated situation... Don't ask.)

So my question remains, can I safely travel from Germany to England alone as an unaccompanied minor?

Also, do I need a visa? (Once again, I am unsure of what a visa is. Sorry.)

Comment: Where is your German passport?

Comment: Do you have a guardian, other than your parents? Someone who can make legal decisions for you?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why do you assume he has one? Most people in Europe don't bother getting a passsport until they need it, and living in the EU there is little chance you will need one unless you want to travel "real far". :-)

Comment: As others have pointed out, your situation very much sounds like you need the help of an adult that you can trust before you start your travel. 
As to you question about visas: A visa from a country allows you to enter that country. Usually visa have restrictions attached to the like "can't stay longer than X days", "can't work while in the country", etc.

Comment: As to your visa situation: You say you "were" an American citizen and are a German citizen. I assume that with "citizen" you refer to the legal status rather than just the fact that you were living there. If you are no longer an American citizen your American passport is no longer valid for travelling. Even if you still have it and the date has not expired it is no longer valid and emigration in Germany and Immigration in the UK likely will notice that. If your only citizenship is German you will need to travel with a German ID: Passport or some countries may also accept a Personalausweis.

Comment: In the long term, it is important to know whether you are a US citizen or not. A person under age 16 is presumed not to have the required maturity and knowing intent to renounce US citizenship. If you are in fact still a US citizen you will have obligations, such as filing US tax returns, even if you never set foot in the US as an adult.

Comment: When you  say "can I safely travel from Germany to England"  what do you mean by safely? Regarding what? Criminality, legal requirements, finding lodging, the person you are visiting? You seem to worry more about the second, but all the rest need to be taken into account.

Comment: "I am moving to England (UK) alone." Move as in going to live there? As an unaccompanied minor, where neither parents is on board? This sounds like emigration while running away from home, not even remotely like regular travel.

Comment: @Chieron Plus, even if somehow ge manages to reach England with no restriction status (his German citizenship), how would one aged 14 go about legally opening a bank account, renting accommodation, joining school (this all assuming he must have a stash of gold somewhere otherwise who would pay for it)?

Comment: Autumn it really sounds like you're in a lot of trouble. Whether of your own making or of your parents is irrelevant - you need help and fast. Based on the answers provided, it sounds like there is a lot of help available to you in Germany - _please_ take advantage of it. As a father who has managed to get three kids through the teenage years, I know they can be exceptionally difficult times. It _will_ get better, but just running isn't the answer!

Comment: I just wanted to add that you might find it hard to live her in the UK as a 14 year old, unless you have some sort of family or someone you trust over here to stay with. For example, it is not legal for a 14 year old to stay anywhere unaccompanied for an evening. [Ref.](https://www.nspcc.org.uk/preventing-abuse/keeping-children-safe/leaving-child-home-alone/). You will also struggle to get a job that offers you enough hours to support yourself since there are pretty strict laws surrounding the amount a 14 year old can work. [ref.](https://www.reed.co.uk/career-advice/jobs-for-14-year-olds/).

Comment: It's only with your best interests in mind, but most people in the UK who see a child of 14 trying to get a job, a place to live or out on the streets will call the NSPCC

Comment: @Bee according to your reference, "there’s no set age for leaving children home alone." Furthermore, the article is about the legal obligations of those caring for children, not about legal requirements imposed on the children themselves.  It does not mean that a 14-year-old breaks the law by staying somewhere alone overnight.

Comment: @phoog if you read the whole article it does say that over night is 14. I was simply point out that, from this, you can extrapolate that no hostle/motel/landlord, is going to assume that responsibility and rent to a child of 14

Comment: @Bee if you read the whole article you will notice that "Children under the age of 16 should not be left alone overnight" is the *advice* of the National Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Children.  It is not a legal opinion, much less a legal requirement.  But I would extrapolate further that no immigration officer is going to allow a child of that age to leave the immigration checkpoint without an idea that the child is going to be in the care of a responsible adult with the permission of the child's legal guardian, be that a parent or otherwise.

Comment: @phong, yes I'm aware of that, however, that has already been mentioned so I was just giving it another perspective. I did have another article which quoted the legal obligation to not leave a child of 14 home alone overnight, but I chose to use nspcc website instead

Comment: @Bee Please quote the legal obligation.  I am pretty sure that (as a blanket prohibition) it doesn't exist.  It's all down to the maturity of the individual child.

Comment: @Martin I'm not spending time looking for the link again, my point is as I stated above, which still stands, legal obligation or not

Comment: You suggest not asking, but an important and relevant piece of information is whether you're emancipated or not.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli Those spelling "mistakes" are differences between US and British spelling, and the OP established having been an American.  You "corrected" things that were already correct.

Answer (score 82):

My answer will be about **how to get help** in a "complicated situation". Other people have already explained that you need permission from your parents to travel; and the police will return you to your parents if they notice you haven't one.

While we do not know you situation, there are a number of ways to get help to resolve a difficult situation. Even if you don't know any adults that you trust, or if you don't want to call the police.

Many Germans speak English quite well. If you do not speak German (or do not speak well), you can still try any of the numbers below and try to speak English. If it does not work, just try and call again.

### If you don't know what to do: 0800 1110111

- If you don't know what to do, you can call the [Telefonseelsorge](https://www.telefonseelsorge.de) - they will try to help with any kind of problem or tell you where to get help:

  - **0800.1110111**
  - **0800.1110222**
  - **116.123**
- You call is **anonymous**. They don't know who you are, and you do not have to give your name or any details.
- People should speak some English. You can try again if they don't.
- You can ask about anything. They will also know where to find more help if needed.
- You can also ask a question online, via chat or app (though you need to read some German to figure out how to log in)

#### Alternatives

- [International helplines](https://www.telefonseelsorge.de/international-helplines/) - there may be one in the country where you come from
- [**Die Nummer gegen Kummer**](https://www.nummergegenkummer.de/kinder-und-jugendtelefon.html). This is a special help line for young people, the number is **116 111**, lines are open from 14:00 to 20:00 (or 2pm to 8pm), except on Sundays
- [A crisis chat that you can use through WhatsApp](https://krisenchat.de)

### Serious problems at home?

- If you have serious problems at home, you can also contact the **Jugendamt**. This is the same as Child Protective Services in the US.

  - To contact them, you can google "Jugendamt" and the name of your city
  - If you go to the police, they will also call the Jugendamt
  - They will eventually contact your parents. But: If they think you are in danger, they will **not** send you home or leave you alone with your parents.
  - They can try to help with the situation at home.
  - If necessary, they can take away your parents' power over you (for example by letting you live in a protected group, or by making some other relative responsible for you).
  - **Important:** Those people will ask for your name, and they **must do something** if they see a problem.

### In danger? Call the police

- If you are in any danger, call the police: **110**
- The Bundespolizei is only responsible for train stations, airports and such. If you call them, they'll put you through to the "normal" police.

### I did not answer the original question

I didn't answer the original question. Other people have already done that, and I agree that the original plan will most likely fail.

I felt it was important to give some concrete leads on where to find help, other than a generic "just talk to someone"; and to make clear that you can call somewhere anonymously if you need to - even if this is somewhat out of scope for Travel SE.

Comment: While it doesn't answer the question asked, it definitely gets to the root of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @RonJohn We have no idea what the situation is. In **every** conceivable case it is better to talk it through with someone who takes your seriously, than to try to "move" to a foreign country without the knowledge or consent of your guardian(s).

Answer (score 59):

If you don't know what a visa is then you haven't begun to understand the complexity of what you seem to be attempting.

You can visit the UK on a US passport without a visa, but you can't live there. If you show up at the UK border you can expect to be asked about your plans. If you don't have a credible plan for your stay, including how you'll return to Germany, you'll be denied entry and returned to Germany, or possibly, depending on your status, sent to the US.

That's probably irrelevant since it's likely that without parental consent you'll be stopped before you can board an aeroplane.

Comment: If he can prove he’s a German (and therefore EU) citizen, can he legally be denied entry to the UK? Not that I’d recommend his proposed course of action of course.

Comment: @Darren Probably not, but there's much that's not clear here. If the OP has German citizenship then they almost certainly no longer have US citizenship since Germany doesn't allow dual citizenship with non-EU countries. Since the OP doesn't understand what a visa is it's likely they don't really understand what citizenship means either. I went with what is clear here, but it remains likely that entry to the UK won't become a concern.

Comment: @Darren a German (or other EU) citizen can legally be denied entry to the UK on grounds that are exceedingly unlikely to apply to a minor (being a threat to public safety, for example), but officers of the UK government are surely also required to protect an unaccompanied minor, whether an EU citizen or otherwise, which will generally mean either establishing that the minor has permission to travel unaccompanied or returning the minor to the authorities of his or her country of residence.

Comment: @ReddHerring it is entirely possible to be a German and US dual citizen.  For example, the child born in the US to German citizens would be.

Comment: @phoog Granted - I hadn't considered that. However, give the OP's evident lack of understanding of visas I don't think we can necessarily take her claims of citizenship at face value. She makes no mention of a German passport, so proving German citizenship for a 14yo at a foreign border will be exceptionally difficult and will attract attention.

Comment: @ReddHerring Regardless of German law, a parent cannot renounce US citizenship on behalf of a child, and it is unusual for a child under 16 to be allowed to renounce. The US probably regards the OP as a citizen. See [Renunciation of U.S. Nationality Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Renunciation-US-Nationality-Abroad.html), especially section F.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I never intended to suggest that the US citizenship was in doubt. The OP does claim a US passport. Rather, the German citizenship is questionable given her lack of understanding.

Comment: The key point though... is due to the unique circumstances.... the OP will most likely not just stopped, but detained.  The parents will then be contacted.  Crossing border is **not** a good way to run away from problems as a minor.  A minor travelling alone across borders **do not** look like this.  Any half-brained border agent will stop the OP cold on these circumstances.

Answer (score 43):

The German Bundespolizei suggests that to leave Germany as a minor you should have a letter by both/all of your legal guardians, stating

- your identity,
- their identity and contact details,
- your travel plans,
- the identity of any adults other than your guardians you're traveling with.

This is completely independent of your passport or immigration status.

Regarding your "complicated" situation, you may feel that adults are not going to help, but if you want **out** of your current situation you will need them.

Google *Kinder- und Jugendnotdienst* and the name of the city you're in. There should be a phone number to call. If you're in a small village, try the name of next large town. You won't have to tell your name to talk with them.

Comment: Note that *Kindernotdienst* generally refers to the emergency *medical* services for children, i.e. where physically ill children should be brought on weekends or late night. The [Kinder- und Jugendnotdienst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinder-_und_Jugendnotdienst) or the local Jugendamt might be a better place to call.

Comment: @berendi, Good point, but how to explain it simply for somebody who speaks no German?

Comment: I've tried to explain just that. Googling for *Kindernotdienst* results in a list of hospitals in the area. Turning up there with a "complicated situation", one would only get a flyer of the nearest *Jugendamt*, possibly with severely outdated contact information. Only when continued exposure to the situation would threaten one's physical or mental health, would a doctor do something about it, e.g. write a cerified recommendation that would help with bureaucracy later on.

Comment: The OP contacting the local Jugendamt about their situation would probably be the best bet (address the *cause* of wanting to travel alone to the UK).  In the event they don't speak English (well enough), they do have access to translators.
Also, in larger German towns, there will be street social workers (often semi-independent) who specialise in working with young people.  At youth clubs (most towns), there will also be social worker (again often independent) to talk to in confidence.

Comment: @Pete, the Jugendamt may side with the parents if they don't accept the cause, so it may be helpful to go to other social services first.

Answer (score 30):

1. If you have a US passport, you don't need a Visa to travel to the UK .
2. Most airlines allow you to travel alone when you are 12 or older. Different airlines have different rules, you should check with your airline
3. Some airlines may require a letter of consent from your parents or guardian (Erziegungsberechtigter)
4. You may get some questioning at check in or at passport control exiting Germany or entering the UK. It's hard to predict what may attract the attention of an officer. If you get questioned, chances are they will want to contact your parents.

Not answering the question: It looks like you are in a difficult situation and you probably need help. Going alone to a different country without the permission or maybe even knowledge of your parents is unlikely to make it better and can get you into a potentially dangerous situation. Before you do anything like this try to reach out to an adult you trust (teacher, relative, guardian, clergy, youth group leader, coach) for a second opinion and some advise.

Answering the question: You need permission from your legal guardians to travel. There are no mandatory controls for this but there is a good chance that someone will take notice and stop you.

Comment: This is all correct, but do need the advice in Redd Herring's answer: if you show your US passport at the UK border and say you're planning to live in the UK, you'll be turned away regardless of your age. As you say you're a German citizen, you should get a German passport - with this you're free to live in the UK.

Comment: The OP would need the support of a parent or legal guardian to get a German passport. See [Passport for applicants under 18 years of age](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/02-PassportsandIDCards/passport-minor/951296)

Comment: @JoeMalt: They would only suspect that you are planning to live there, if you tell them

Comment: If you manage to get to the UK you can expect Immigration to ask you questions along the lines of ’where will you be staying’, ‘how long will you be in the UK and do you have a return ticket (or proof you’re planning to leave’, ‘who is supporting you financially while you’re in the UK’, and ‘do you have your parents’ permission to be in the UK (and out of school). You can probably also expect Immigration to call any contact name you give them to verify your story.

Comment: Immigration officials generally will not take "It's a complicated situation, don't ask" for an answer. They are going to want a thorough explanation, with supporting documentation. Unless OP presents evidence of an extraordinary situation, the officials will probably contact the parents and arrange to return OP to their custody. If that somehow does *not* happen, then the next step is likely going to be an international custody battle between OP's parents and some arm of the UK government. There is basically no situation where OP "just walks out of the airport."

Comment: @JoeMalt He won't need a passport, his German ID card will be enough, and at 14 he most probably has one (not sure what's the minimun requred age in Germany).

Comment: @DiegoSánchez: Personalausweis ID cards are mandatory from age 16, but they can be issued before that, which involves consent by all(!) legal guardians.

Comment: Small typo: "Erziegungsberechtigter" -> "Erziehungsberechtigter" (doesn't have anything to do with goats)

Comment: @Hilmar You don't get unaccompanied 14-year-olds with a German ID card and a (no longer valid) US passport arriving at UK airports every day of the week. Any half-awake airport official will want to know the back story. Illegal child trafficking is a thing!

Comment: @alephzero As s side note, it is mostly possible to travel between many EU states as an EU citizen without passing through passport control unless you are flying. You might get stopped, but for Schengen zone countries there are, afaik, no border control points. Now, UK is *not* in Schengen, but Germany and eg France is. I am not aware of how tight is border control on Calais-Dover ferry or Eurotunnel, but flying to UK doesn't seem like the only option, despite OP suggesting taking a flight.

Comment: @gnudiff I've traveled to the UK via plane, ferry and Eurotunnel and the controls are the same everywhere.

Comment: @UlrichSchwartz out of curiosity, how common is it in Germany to wait until you are 16? At least in Spain it seems to be pretty common to need it at a much younger age.

Comment: @alephzero the US passport appears to be valid, but with a valid German ID card it would not be necessary to show the US passport regardless.

Comment: @JoeMalt Free movement in the EU does *not* mean you can live wherever you want without any requirements. It's free movement for *workers* and I'm not aware of exceptions for single minors.

Comment: @gnudiff You can fly perfectly fine inter-schengen without any passport controls as long as you don't check in luggage. I never have to show any passport on business trips (surprised me the first time too). They are allowed to control you though, so a 14 year old might very well get more scrutiny than a business traveller.

Comment: @alephzero On the other hand, unaccompanied travelling minors is *very* common within the EU (though of course easier within the Schengen area, where there are usually no controls of any kind). It shouldn’t generally raise an eyebrow. Child trafficking exists but compared to the total number of minors travelling within the EU it’s almost certainly a drop in the ocean.

Comment: (And just to clarify my previous comment: Unaccompanied minors should definitely carry with them a letter on behalf of their guardians just in case but there are no systematic checks although given that the UK has border controls, such checks are infinitely more likely.)

Answer (score 22):

Frame challenge (, I think they say here ....)

@Autumn - how do you plan on supporting yourself when arriving in the UK?

As a minor, you will not be able to work, rent property, or open a bank account in the UK.  I don't know your situation, but as you've not mentioned friends or family I'm concerned you may be planning to meet somebody you've met on the internet.  If this isn't the case - please ignore!

But if it is - be aware that people you meet online may not be what they seem.  Please, at the least, talk it over with some trusted friends, relatives or teachers, and listen to what they say.

Comment: This is a very real possibility which should have been raised sooner.  If you can expand the answer a bit and address it to OP rather than the admins, it should stand in its own right.

Comment: Thanks @phoog.  As stated, I'm new here.  I've edited to address the OP as best I can, but please dive in and improve if you can.  Ta.

Comment: I agree, I don't think there's an EU country where you could legally be employed before you're 16, not to a degree where you could hope to become self-sufficient.  So if anyone is offering to support or employ you, the job can only be illegal, and is likely to be both unpleasant and downright dangerous.  Prostitution rings recruit precisely like this, emphasizing differences with parents to vulnerable young people. Please, please OP try to talk to an adult you trust before going off on an adventure that could end very badly

Comment: "*I'm concerned you may be planning to meet somebody you've met on the internet.*" That's the first thing I thought when reading "it's complicated ... don't ask".

Comment: @GeorgeM The limit is 15, but can be higher in certain EU countries. There are restrictions for people under 18 that must be fulfilled.

Answer (score 6):

> (Once again, I am unsure of what a visa is. Sorry.)

Citizens are allowed to live and work in their homeland. Foreigners need permission. The details depend on the laws of the *destination* country, the country of *origin* of the applicant, and the length and purpose of stay.

- Sometimes the application must be made before arrival. This is called a **visa** or an ESTA. The applicant fills a form and usually she sends the passport in to have a stamp or sticker added. (The US insists that an ESTA is different from a visa, but if it quacks like a duck, it probably is a duck.)
- Sometimes the application can be made at the border on arrival. This is called a **visa on arrival** or some other names. There is a stamp in the passport and a time limit for the visitor to leave.
- Sometimes no stamp is necessary and no record is made, really **visa-free** travel. That only happens if the countries trust each other that there will be no illegal immigration or similar problems.

As a German citizen, you are a **citizen of the European Union**. With your parents' permission, you can travel to any of the 28 EU member states. Once you are old enough, you can live and work there. The exception would be if you, personally, get deported and banned from an EU state, but you would have to do something outrageous to make this happen.

You *cannot get* a visa for any EU member unless you lie about your German citizenship, because you *don't need* one.

You will *need no passport* in the EU once you have your German identity card (*Personalausweis*) at age 16.

The United Kingdom is about to leave the EU. It is unclear when that will happen and which rules apply afterwards, but in all likelihood you will either need a visa on arrival or no visa at all for a visit. Living and working there will require permission.

Some EU states (and some others) have formed the Schengen travel area. This actually makes little difference for you, because you have visa-free travel in those states anyway.

Answer (score 5):

**The bad:**

- You can travel as tourist using your American passport to the UK for up to 6 months.

  - You cannot move and start living in the UK using your American passport. You would need a visa for that (without a parent/guardian **and money** you will highly likely not be able to get it).
  - If you manage to arrive to the UK border and you mention you want to move here forever, you will be sent back to Germany (letting your parents know where you are).
- You can immigrate (moving to a different country permanently) to the UK using your German ID card or passport.

  - Being 14 I will be very surprised if no one stops you and you succeed. They will probably tell your parents when they stop you.

And actually the interesting question is from me to you:
What are you planning to do if you arrive to the UK?

To pay for accommodation (place to live) you need a parent or a guardian (an adult who is legally responsible for you), to join school you need a parent/guardian, to sign up for a doctor you need a parent/guardian, bank account - parent guardian, you cannot really do anything without a parent/guardian until you're 18. It might not seem so but most of the things you've done so far in your life is because a parent or a guardian agreed to it.

**The good:**

Now, on the **bright** side, this all gives you one good option. Right now, you need to find someone, an adult, you can speak with or who you trust. School teacher? Doctor? Dentist? Your best friends parents? You can speak to anyone from the government (policeman/policelady, fireman, ambulance people). You can just walk into a police station, your doctors building or any other building where these people are and they will listen to you. Tell them about your parents and what happened. Unfortunately, without any adult you cannot do much until you're 18, so you need to find someone who you can talk to and they should listen and help.

If you are scared, you can also call them for free and explain your parents situation and they will help - **0800 6 888 000**

If you don't do that, your only option is go back to your parents. Pick which of the two you want.

Comment: You've said "you can also call them for free" - who exactly is "them" referring to?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the number I used is for Bundes­polizei, there of course can be a more related number for this specific case (government people/charities who help children) but I don't know what number that would be unfortunately.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if your answer explicitly said that, so they have some idea who to expect to be talking to if/when they decide to use it (which hopefully they will). Your previous paragraph mentions lots of different options so if you don't know the number it's not clear who it is for.

Comment: See my answer. The Bundespolizei may not be not best place to call if you're a young person and in trouble. Their responsibility is trains, airports and such and in the best case they'll put you through to the "normal" police, or make you call 110. It is also important to know that there is an option to call someone who is **not** the police, if in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue for you that nobody mentioned so far, is that nobody can accommodate you. Hotels, hostels, Airbnbs etc. won't accommodate unaccompanied minors.

And if you are travelling to the U.K. to stay with a non-family member without permissions from your parents, your parents can file criminal charges against said person, and have you deported back to them in Germany.

You are also not allowed to stay longer than 3 (or maybe 6) months in the UK without a residency permit (which you cannot obtain as a minor)

So in short, what you're asking is not feasible.

(This advice applies to all minors travlling, not just for people in OPs situation)

Comment: There's a comment to the question: `how would one aged 14 go about legally opening a bank account, renting accommodation, joining school (this all assuming he must have a stash of gold somewhere otherwise who would pay for it)`

Comment: @BernhardDöbler well, this answers at least part of it :) Which is to say, not possible. (And a lot of good answers in this thread for minors traveling in general)

Answer (score 2):

A visa is a document from a country that authorizes the identified individual into that country and defines what they are allowed to do while in that country (school, work, apply for residence) and how long they are allowed to stay. It is typically attached to a passport.

If you have either a US or German passport a visa is not required for a visit, if you intend to stay indefinitely that would change.

As a practical matter, if you fly into the UK you are going to go through an immigration checkpoint, and as an unaccompanied minor, they are going to want to know where you will be staying and with who, the purpose of your visit and how long you will be staying.  Note that these are questions they can and do ask adults, the main difference being that as a minor, instead of refusing entry, you will probably be taken into protective custody and held pending arrangements to return you to the physical custody of your parents.

Imagine a parent and a 8 year old traveling together, where the parent dies during the flight — while officials are determining what to do (return the child to home country, hand them off to a relative in the destination, whatever), the one thing they aren’t going to do is stamp their passport and let them wander away. You will be in the same position.